# YouTube RTSP URL playback inside VideoView - low quality

Tags: android, url, youtube, video-streaming

I want to stream YouTube video inside an Android application using VideoView.

Everything seems to be fine, playback starts for specified RTSP URL, but the quality of the video is really really poor.

Does anyone know how to get RTSP URL with better (HD) quality?

It seems that JSON object does contain two urls for RSTP locations, but both are in the same very low quality.

I know it is not strictly programming question, but maybe anyone had the same problem?

Thanks.

Bartek.

Answer (score 0):

To make High quality, put &fmt=18 or &fmt=22 in front of link. Source.

http://www.youtube.com/user/GTdude89

Comment: Does this also apply to rtsp link?